# Python Requests Client Side certificates Exception has occurred: ConnectionError

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to move a request that occurs in Postman successfully, to a Python request. I started with the Python code snippet that Postman provides:

```
import requests

url = "example.com/request"

payload='auth_type=client_credentials'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': 'Basic auth_token'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

However, this needs updating to include SSL verification, as described on the vendors site:

> Configure the transport certs in Postman.

> Go to Settings > Certificates > Add Certificate

> Staging: *.staging.example.com:*

> Sandbox: *.sandbox.example.com:*

This is as client certificates. A few other configuration items as described on the vendor site have also been added. Therefore I've updated my code in this way:

```
url = "example.com/request"

payload='auth_type=client_credentials'
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Authorization': 'Basic auth_token'
}
S = requests.Session()
cert = ("/path/to/.pem", "/path/to/.key")    

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, cert=cert, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)

print(response.text)
```

However, whether I pass both pem and key as a tuple, or if I only select the pem/key individually, then it's no joy I receive:

> Exception has occurred: ConnectionError
> ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted'))

Pastebin link to the exception printed:
https://pastebin.com/kSsnVUPm

Comment: Normally exception stacktraces include much more information, such as the line that triggered the exception. That information is very useful and should be included in your question.

Comment: I've added a link to a pastebin for a printout of the try catch. I didn't see it originally as I was paused on a breakpoint before it printed.

Comment: Looking at the error myself, I think it means that my certificate is encrypted? I only have the .key and the .pem. Looking at the pem in a text editor, it shows there are two certificates, (both denoted "BEGIN CERTIFICATE", "END CERTIFICATE") 

The .key file is just one "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY"

It also seems that requests doesn't support encrypted certs?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is entirely embarrassing. I've now realised the error is not to do with the request not working, it's MacOS protecting me from my own code, by not allowing access to the certificate files on the Downloads folder.